# iTunes under Windows: A utility to stop/unload any background services started by iTunes

Tags: windows, itunes

I am a iPod Video, iPod Touch owner. I have iTunes running now on an old, slow Celeron machine so that I don't have to run it on my fast main machine. I am worried about the services it loads and starts on under Windows.

But it would be cool if I could install and run it on my main machine an exit from it without it leaving a footprint. Short of running it in a Virtual Machine, is there any utility out there that could toggle on/off the services that iTunes/Quicktime runs in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are looking for has been written up in a great article at [ghacks.net](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/06/07/disable-applemobiledeviceserviceexe-ituneshelperexe-and-ipodserviceexe/). The article goes through how to disable AppleMobileDeviceService.Exe, iTunesHelper.exe and iPodService.exe.

Comment: @fideli: Excellent information. Unfortunately, I do own an iPod Touch. I need these services sometimes. But the article gives enough info to figure out how to disable, then enable what is needed.